# window.history.pushState not affecting history

Tags: javascript

I'm using regular JavaScript, no libraries.

I'm successfully using `window.history.pushState()` to change my URLs when I make an AJAX request, but the problem is that while it now allows me to go back and forth in my history, it doesn't actually change the content (i.e. the URL is not loading).

I'm using

```
var histTitle = "Page title";
var histUrl = "/url.html";
window.history.pushState({},histTitle,histUrl);
```

I don't really know what to do with the first parameter, which is meant to be an object, but I don't know exactly what to do here so have left it as `{}`.

I'm also assuming the second parameter is the title that shows up when viewing your browser's history?

So the problem I'm having is how to get the URL to actually load when using my browser's back and forward buttons.

Comment: I thought the point of `history.pushState()` was to handle page loading manually, so the browser wasn't navigating (allowing asynchronously loaded content to have a "url" without hash workarounds)? Otherwise, you'd just let the browser navigate to the URL. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries